# How to use recursion to exit correctly for House Robber implementation?

Tags: swift, algorithm, recursion, iteration, dynamic-programming

I'm doing the [House Robber challenge](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/description/).

> You are a professional robber planning to rob houses along a street.
>   Each house has a certain amount of money stashed, the only constraint
>   stopping you from robbing each of them is that adjacent houses have
>   security system connected and it will automatically contact the police
>   if two adjacent houses were broken into on the same night.
>
> Given a list of non-negative integers representing the amount of money
>   of each house, determine the maximum amount of money you can rob
>   tonight without alerting the police.

My **code**:

```
class Solution {
    func rob(_ nums: [Int]) -> Int {
        var mostMoneyRobbed = 0

        func rob(neighborUnits: [Int], startfromUnit unit: Int, didRobAdjacentUnit: Bool, totalMoneyRobbed total: Int){

            if total > mostMoneyRobbed{
                mostMoneyRobbed = total
            }
            for i in unit...neighborUnits.count - 1{
                if i == neighborUnits.count - 1{
                    if !didRobAdjacentUnit{
                        if total + nums[i] > mostMoneyRobbed{                                
                            mostMoneyRobbed = total + nums[i]                                
                        }
                    }
                    return
                }

                if didRobAdjacentUnit{
                    rob(neighborUnits: nums, startfromUnit: unit + 1, didRobAdjacentUnit: false, totalMoneyRobbed: total)
                }else{
                    rob(neighborUnits: nums, startfromUnit: unit + 1, didRobAdjacentUnit: true, totalMoneyRobbed: total + nums[i])
                    rob(neighborUnits: nums, startfromUnit: unit + 1, didRobAdjacentUnit: false, totalMoneyRobbed: total)
                }
            }            
        }
        guard nums.count > 0 else {
            return 0
        }

        rob(neighborUnits: nums, startfromUnit: 0, didRobAdjacentUnit: true, totalMoneyRobbed: 0)
        rob(neighborUnits: nums, startfromUnit: 0, didRobAdjacentUnit: false, totalMoneyRobbed: 0)

        return mostMoneyRobbed
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let s = Solution()
print(s.rob([1,2,3])) // returns 5 instead of 4
```

---

My **iteration** strategy is:

- if the previous has was robbed then I can only *not* rob at my next iteration.
- if the previous has was not robbed then I can *either* rob or not at my next iteration. Obviously to find all valid robberies I do both!

My **exit** strategy is done at the line below:

```
if i == neighborUnits.count - 1{
```

basically if I reach the end of the units the iteration will stop.

Then I compare the value with `mostMoneyRobbed` and if it's bigger I set my value to that. 
At the end of the loop I just return `mostMoneyRobbed`

yet after reach the last element of the block and returning my code continues to proceed!!!! I don't understand why. It should be something very trivial

**Kindly note** I don't want alternate solutions. I want to fix my own implementation.

Comment: What is your question? how to exit? For your example I think the result should be 5 ? 1 + 3 + 1 = 5

Comment: 1, **3**,  **1** is incorrect. Because the bolded houses are adjacent

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but did you try to *debug* the code? With an array of 4 elements it should be feasible to  single-step through all calls. At what point is the program flow not at you expect it to be?

Comment: @MartinR Yes. I placed a lot of prints to debug. But apparently I'm missing something. Maybe I'm tired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I'm iterating through two means. A 'for loop' and `unit + 1`. I kinda messed up in the core of my recursion. Not using the 'for loop' and using only the `unit + 1` was all that was needed.

```
class Solution {
    func rob(_ nums: [Int]) -> Int {
        var mostMoneyRobbed = 0

        func rob(neighborUnits: [Int], startfromUnit unit: Int, didRobAdjacentUnit: Bool, totalMoneyRobbed total: Int){

            if total > mostMoneyRobbed{
                mostMoneyRobbed = total
            }
            if unit == neighborUnits.count - 1{
                if !didRobAdjacentUnit{
                    if total + nums[unit] > mostMoneyRobbed{
                        mostMoneyRobbed = total + nums[unit]
                    }
                }
                return
            }

            if didRobAdjacentUnit{
                rob(neighborUnits: nums, startfromUnit: unit + 1, didRobAdjacentUnit: false, totalMoneyRobbed: total)
            }else{
                rob(neighborUnits: nums, startfromUnit: unit + 1, didRobAdjacentUnit: true, totalMoneyRobbed: total + nums[unit])
                rob(neighborUnits: nums, startfromUnit: unit + 1, didRobAdjacentUnit: false, totalMoneyRobbed: total)
            }
        }
        guard nums.count > 1 else{
            if nums.count == 0{
                return 0
            }else{
                return nums[0]
            }
        }

        rob(neighborUnits: nums, startfromUnit: 0, didRobAdjacentUnit: true, totalMoneyRobbed: 0)
        rob(neighborUnits: nums, startfromUnit: 0, didRobAdjacentUnit: false, totalMoneyRobbed: 0)

        return mostMoneyRobbed
    }
}
```

So far this has worked as expected. On LeetCode I got a **Time Limit Exceeded** error on the 49th test case! :D

[image]

Comment: Hint: Look for a non-recursive solution :)

Comment: I know. This is just the approach I came up by solving similar problems and I just wanted to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the DP approach to solve the time limit exceeded problem. As it will remove unnecessary recursive calls as we are storing in DP
you can create one DP array and store the already computed results in the DP array and compare the max amount if we add the new amount to the previous one is greater than the amount currently available. like this max(dp[index - 2] + nums[index], dp[index - 1]).

```
    class Solution {
    func rob(_ nums: [Int]) -> Int {
        
        if nums.count == 0 {
            return 0
        }
        
        if nums.count == 1 {
            return nums[0]
        }
        
        if nums.count == 2 {
            return max(nums[0], nums[1])
        }
        
        var dp = [Int]()
        dp.append(nums[0])
        dp.append(max(nums[0], nums[1]))
        for index in 2..<nums.count {
            dp.append(max(dp[index - 2] + nums[index], dp[index - 1]))
        }
        return dp[nums.count - 1]
    }
    
}
```